# How to save and restore state of process in Activiti framework

Tags: activiti, bpmn

My aim is to save state of process before Activiti application will be redeployed with new futures. So I can restore all not finished process in state which they had before stopping. Is there a way how I can do it by using Activiti functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activiti framework saves all tasks  and processes into DB. After activiti angine was terminated and lunched again all not finished tasks will be restored.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to suspend?
If so, you can use the public API RepositoryService.suspendProcessDefinitionById.
https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#api.services.suspend

https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/RepositoryService.html#suspendProcessDefinitionById-java.lang.String-

https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/RepositoryService.html#suspendProcessDefinitionById-java.lang.String-boolean-java.util.Date-

Answer (score 0):

You can use Variables to save state of process instance.
https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#apiVariables

https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/RuntimeService.html#setVariable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/RuntimeService.html#getVariable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-